# HTML + CSS - Expanding Image to hold Text

Tags: html, css, image

[image]

I have the image shown below (blue bubble) and I will need to put text behind it.

The amount of text will change frequently so I need to be able to have the image expand (vertically) to hold more text.

Hoping to get a tap in the right direction with this one. Can't see to get my head around how to get the image to expand with the amount of text...

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div {
background:url('myimage.jpg') no-repeat;
width:0 auto; /* add fixed width if need only to expand vertically */
height:0 auto;
padding:5px;
background-size:cover; /* background-size:100% 100%; */
}
```

Instead make the image background of div! The div will automatically adjust its width and height ;)